# Как верстать внутри шаблона Joomla?

Tags: php, html, gulp, cms, joomla

Подскажите, заказчик запросил верстку именно уже внутри существующего joomla шаблона. Верстать нужно с помощью gulp сборки. Подскажите, как начать, что именно он имел ввиду?

Comment: Ну наверное имелось ввиду что-то вроде фулстек разработки в уже существующей Joomla теме, предположу что изначально использовался какой-то стартер для этого. Скорее всего в самой теме лежит gulpfile с неким конфигом который отслеживает изменения в файлах данной темы. Как-то так. А там уже в зависимости от задач, разрабатываете/дорабатываете необходимые части темы и тп.

Comment: Для того чтобы использовать препроцессор (а не писать на css), для того чтобы получать минимизированные файлы, объединять однотипные файлы в один файл, пользоваться живым обновлением. Вот пример gulp-сборщика для joomla (https://github.com/phproberto/joomla-gulp).

Comment: @АлексейОбухов , а у вас не будет минутки, чтобы помочь? Может в телеграме подскажите?

Comment: я не люблю мессенджеры, можете на почту написать вопросы (сразу скажу, что я не специалист по joomla), почта указана на моем гитхабе (ссылка на него есть в профиле, в самом профиле не нашел, где указать почту)